# Flex: How do I adjust the contrast/brightness of an image inside an image control?

Tags: apache-flex, image-manipulation

I have an image loaded into an `Image` control and I'd like to know the most efficient way that I can darken/lighten the image programatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Adobe's [BitmapFilter](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/filters/BitmapFilter.html) class. You can do some pretty cool things with it. Especially take a look at its derived classes and their usage examples.

Comment: Thanks Robusto, the ColorMatrixFilter and ShaderFilter both work great - and there are a lot of other things as well!

Answer (score 0):

Although I went with Robusto's method, I also found this that works well

```
var a:Number = value * 11;
var b:Number = 63.5 - (value * 698.5);
redValue = greenValue = blueValue = a;
redOffset = greenOffset = blueOffset = b;
var cmf:ColorMatrixFilter = new ColorMatrixFilter(a, 0, 0, 0, b, 0, a, 0, 0, b, 0, 0, a, 0, b, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

It was taken from here, [Image Manipulation In Flex](http://www.insideria.com/2008/03/image-manipulation-in-flex.html) and there is much more image altering fun as well.